# With Prometheus how to monitor a scaled Docker service where each instance serves its own /metrics?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I have a Prometheus setup that monitors metrics exposed by my own services. This works fine for a single instance, but once I start scaling them, Prometheus gets completely confused and starts tracking incorrect values.

All services are running on a single node, through docker-compose.

This is the job in the `scrape_configs`:

```
  - job_name: 'wowanalyzer'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['prod:8000']
```

Each instance of `prod` tracks metrics in its memory and serves it at `/metrics`. I'm guessing Prometheus picks a random container each time it scraps which leads to the huge increase in counts recorded, building up over time. Instead I'd like Prometheus to read `/metrics` on all instances simultaneously, regardless of the amount of instances active at that time.

Comment: Maybe with https://monitor.dockerflow.com/?

Comment: I'm planning to fix this by using Docker Swarm in combination with Prometheus DNS service discovery similar to what is explained here: https://airtame.engineering/practical-services-monitoring-with-prometheus-and-docker-30abd3cf9603#4477 Docker Flow Monitor seems like a valid alternative but with more complexity.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, can you share it?

Comment: I did not. :( It has actually been running in this broken state since I made the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-gen (https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen) was developed for this purpose.

You would need to create a sidecart container running docker-gen that generates a new set of targets.

If I remember well the host names generated are `prod_1`, `prod_2`, `prod_X`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot to find something to help us with this issue but it looks an unsolved issue.

So, I decided to create this tool that helps us with this service-discovery.

https://github.com/juliofalbo/docker-compose-prometheus-service-discovery

Feel free to contribute and open issues!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DNS service discovery feature. For example:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  myapp:
    image: appimage:v1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - back
  prometheus:
    image: "prom/prometheus:v2.32.1"
    container_name: "prometheus"
    restart: "always"
    ports: [ "9090:9090" ]
    volumes:
      - "./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      - "prometheus_data:/prometheus"
    networks:
      - back
```

`prometheus.yml` sample:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 60s
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'monitoringjob'
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names: [ 'myapp' ] <-- service name from docker-compose 
        type: 'A'
        port: 8080
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
```

You can check your DNS records using nslookup util from any container in this network:

```
docker exec -it myapp bash
bash-4.2# yum install bind-utils
bash-4.2# nslookup myapp
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   myapp
Address: 172.22.0.2
Name:   myapp
Address: 172.22.0.7
```